# How to get sub-node of JSON-File in gatsby/react

Tags: reactjs, json, axios, gatsby

I want to create Azure Static Web App based on gatsby framework. I am quite new to gatsby/react/javascript development.

I created a GET-Request via axios in my gatsby-node.js file.

```
const getBlogs = endpoint => axios.get(`https://example.com/data-api/rest/blogs${endpoint}`);

 const getBlogsData = ids =>
  Promise.all(
    ids.map(async id => {
      const { data: blogs } = await getBlogs(`/glogs/${id}`);
      return { ...blogs };
    })
  );

 exports.createPages = async ({ actions: { createPage } }) => {
    const allBlogs = await getBlogsData(['1', '2', '3', '4']);
```

My reponse of allBlogs object looks like:

```
[
  { value: [ [Object] ] },
  { value: [ [Object] ] },
  { value: [ [Object] ] },
  { value: [ [Object] ] }
]
```

At the end I want to parse an array with the results/data to my gatsby-component
My gatsby component looks like:

```
const ListBlogsComp = ({ pageContext: { allRezepte } }) => {
   return (
    <div style={{ width: 960, margin: '4rem auto' }}>
    <h1>ListBlogsComp</h1>
    {allBlogs.map(blog=> (
        <li key={blog.id}>
          <h2>{blog.id}</h2>
          <p>{glog.name}</p>
        </li>
      ))}
  </div>

  );
}
```

How can I access the data?
How can I remove the "value" node to show the real data in my component/html-file?

I try to find a function like "value". Do I have to convert my variable into an other data type and then parse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remap the data structure and remove the extra "value" key, you can use the map function to transform the data in your gatsby-node.js file before passing it to your component.

```
exports.createPages = async ({ actions: { createPage } }) => {
  const allBlogsData = await getBlogsData(['1', '2', '3', '4']);

  // Remap the data structure
  const allBlogs = allBlogsData.map(blog => blog.value[0]);//also i think i am seeing 2 array there so it might be blog.value[0][0]
```

Comment: sweet..........

Answer (score 0):

I added the code snippet into my gatsby-config.js file. In "gatsby develop" the entire code works, in my deployed Azure Static Web App it returns the following error message:

> error "gatsby-node.js" threw an error while running the createPages lifecycle: Request failed with status code 500